# Unable to Add Users/Groups in file security permissions on Azure File share

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-file-share

looking for help!
I have created an Azure VM & a file share(**R**) under storage account and  mounted it to my local and VM , Now when I'm trying to add users or groups in file permissions(security tab)
Getting two error popups as mentioned in the below screenshot.

popup message 1: **The program cannot open the required dialog box because it cannot determine whether the computer named "xyz" is joined to a domain"**

imediate popup message 2: **Unable to display the user selection dialog, The RPC server is unavailable.**

[image]

## **Note : I am having a similar file share(z) attached to my local and other VM in different resource group which if perfectly working fine as it's allowing to add users and edit permissions**

Thanks in advance.

Troubleshootings tried:

1. Removed VM from my domain and added again
   2: ipconfig /flushdns.

Comment: I resolved it ,  Actually I forgot to configure my Azure file share with Active Directory Domain services , Now after configuring it, issue got resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below.***

[image]

To resolve this issue:

- Click on security -> Advanced

[image]

- Click on ***Owner tab***-> Advanced

[image]

- Click ****`Find Now`****, check your ***current user account*** and select your user account from the list. Check the full control to allow and click ***yes*** if any security warning appears.

[image]

- Now, open file explorer -> select **More** > **Map network drive** in that folder if you network type name is `STORAGE-1234` and the folder name is `Imran`. Make sure to change like this `\\STORAGE-1234\Imran`

[image]

- In start bar, type Run -> **`services.msc`** -> select -> windows firewall -> disable. In the event if you are prompted for administrator password or confirmation, enter your password or choose Continue.

[image]

- Click start-> Control panel -> Network and internet -> Network and sharing center-> Change advance sharing setting -> click on Public network and allow like below.

[image]

If you are still facing The RPC server is unavailable. Please check this reference: [Ref1](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/rpc-server-is-unavailable-error-on-windows-10-fixed/) & [Ref2](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/rpc_server_unavailable_rds.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time Imran, Appreciated!, Actually I forgot to configure my Azure file share with Active Directory Domain services , Now after configuring it issue got resolved